# Creating diagonal matrix from array of matrices in MATLAB

Tags: arrays, matlab, matrix, diagonal

I am interested how to create a diagonal matrix from an array of matrices.
I created an array of matrices in MATLAB:

`X<62x62x1000>` it consists of 1000 matrices with dimensions 62x62

I want to create a matrix of dimensions 62000x62000 with 1000 sub matrices from array X along main diagonal.

Do you have any clue how to do this, except `M=blkdiag(X(:,:,1), X(:,:,2), X(:,:,3)...)` because that would be to much writing.

Comment: https://de.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/diag.html

Answer (score 1):

A possible solution

```
M = kron(speye(1000),ones(62));
M(logical(M)) = X(:);
```

With `kron` a 62000*62000 sparse matrix `M` is created that contains 1000 blocks of ones on its diagonal, then replace ones with elements of `X`.

Answer (score 0):

You can flatten out your input matrix into a column vector using `(:)` indexing and then pass it to [`diag`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/diag.html) to place these elements along the diagonal of a new matrix.

```
result = diag(X(:))
```

This will order the elements along the diagonal in column-major order (the default for MATLAB). If you want a different ordering, you can use `permute` to re-order the dimensions prior to flattening.

It's important to note that your resulting matrix is going to be quite large. You could use [`spdiags`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/spdiags.html) instead to create a sparse diagonal matrix

```
spdiags(X(:), 0, numel(X), numel(X))
```

Answer (score 0):

A very controversial eval call can solve this very lazily, although I suspect there is a much better way to do this:

```
evalstring = ['M=blkdiag('];
for i = 1:999
    evalstring = [evalstring, 'X(:,:,', num2str(i),'),'];
end
evalstring = [evalstring, 'X(:,:,1000));'];
eval(evalstring);
```